# Why can't MikTex find all of my style files?

Tags: packages, miktex

I was wondering if you could help me please.  I'm using `MiKTeX 2.9` and `WinEdt` on `Windows 7` and I've tried to add the style files that I need to use for a particular project to the search path for `MiKTeX`.

I created a folder called `Local` within `My Documents` and then within that another folder called `Tex` and then added the folder containing all of my style files to the Tex folder.

Next I added `C:/../MyDocuments/Local` as a root directory with `MiKTeX`.  When I try to build a LaTeX document, however, it seems that `MiKTeX` can find some but not all of my style files.  I've double checked and they are all in there, so I'm not sure as to why it can't find some of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't forget to press FNDB after making a new root. And your TeX input file (that uses the style) must not be in the root directory you just created.

Comment: Thanks-I hadn't pressed FNDB.  After pressing it, it works.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, but apparently my reputation isn't high enough :(  When my reputation goes up enough, I'll definitely do it :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still 2 reputation points short though.  I will do it as soon as I can :)